# Whats app registration issue. Stuck on the 'Initializing' page

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I 'Cleared Data' on whatsApp by mistake while closing some applications. Ever since, WhatsApp is trying to re-register me and I am stuck on the 'Initializing' page for the last 48 hours. However, I can continue to receive WhatsApp notifications and see that I am receiving messages. But if I click on WhatsApp, it takes me to the 'Initializing' page! Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to to make sure of the version of the messenger you have is (Version 2.11.169), and then try to download the application manually from whatsapp website (http://www.whatsapp.com/android/) and install it manually, while installing it it will ask for replacement, hit yes and continue installing, this will give you the previlage to avoid losing all previous data and to recover whatsapp's data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked. But I lost my recent messages...

Answer (score 0):

Even i had faced this issue and my initialisation was stuck with the 4-5mins timer auto activation.I simply did a restart for my device and then after few time opened the application and pressed continue to load the initialisation page. With good internet connection I was able to get back to normal what's app and the best part is that I did not lose any previous chat history it loaded back as it was.

Or

Go for voice activation wherein you get a call for a one time password through which also you can get back in the account.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the app, clear cache and if required, reboot. This is a common issue during setup.
Wiping data and restarting the setup too will work.